# Angular js - ngDialog how to open dialog from a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, ng-dialog

Hi i installed the following module https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog

it works great but i can't get how to open the dialog box from a controller, i do:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ngSanitize','ngDialog']);

app.controller('SignupController', function($rootScope,$scope) {
    $scope.signup = function(){
        var error = false,
        error_list = "ERRORS";

        if(!$scope.signup_username){
            error = true;
            error_list += "\n\n Username \n " + $rootScope.errors.required_field;
        }if(!$scope.signup_email){
            error = true;
            error_list += "\n\n Email \n " + $rootScope.errors.valid_email;
        }if(!$scope.signup_password){
            error = true;
            error_list += "\n\n Password \n " + $rootScope.errors.required_field;
        }

        if(error){
            ngDialog.open({template:error_list,plain:true});
        }else{
            //register
        }
    }

});
```

But it doesn't works as expected, cause i get console error : **ngDialog is not defined**.

Comment: Why rollback my edit? I thought it was an improvement.

Comment: @Tshepang you're welcome man but it is really ok as it is :)

Comment: Not really. It has a tag in the title; not acceptable around here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your controller is not taking a dependency on ngDialog so it is an unknown variable at runtime.

```
app.controller('SignupController', function($rootScope, $scope, ngDialog) {
    $scope.signup = function(){
        var error = false,
        error_list = "ERRORS";

        if(!$scope.signup_username){
            error = true;
            error_list += "\n\n Username \n " + $rootScope.errors.required_field;
        }if(!$scope.signup_email){
            error = true;
            error_list += "\n\n Email \n " + $rootScope.errors.valid_email;
        }if(!$scope.signup_password){
            error = true;
            error_list += "\n\n Password \n " + $rootScope.errors.required_field;
        }

        if(error){
            ngDialog.open({template:error_list,plain:true});
        }else{
            //register
        }
    }
});
```